# PHP Clear all Variables from Above Certain Line

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, optimization

I'm trying to Optimize a Resource Intensive PHP Script for Speed, say I have over 200 variables above it because that's around about correct, when I reach a certain line I want to clear everything from above, is there Anyway of doing this? Would getting the already set variables to an array and unsetting them be the best option or has PHP got a built in function that could handle this?

Comment: It doesn't exactly.  But what is stopping you from writing one of your own?  Like, make a "clearThis" function that gets called whenever you want to wipe out a certain set of variables.

Comment: because Listing all the variables in an array to unset them would add extra memory usage to the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). When you exit the lower scope, all variables are effectively unset.

Something along these lines:

```
function doLotsOfStuff() {
    //Use 200 variables, etc.
}

function doMoreStuff() {
    //Do other stuff, not using the above variables, which are no longer stored
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I'll make it the answer when Stack Overflow Lets me in approximately 3 minutes. You sir are a life saver